# moving the circle with mouse cursor?

Tags: c++, qt

I want to move the circle by the cursor but this code moves me the image by the cursor.
how to move the circle according to the cursor.

`label.cpp`

```
void Label::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent* event){
    mousePressed = true; 
    mCirc.setTopLeft(event->pos());
    mCirc.setBottomRight(event->pos());

    offset = event->pos();
}

void Label::mouseMoveEvent ( QMouseEvent * mouse_event )
{
    if(mouse_event->type() == QEvent::MouseMove &&  mousePressed == true)
    {
        mCirc.setBottomRight(mouse_event->pos());
    }

    update();
    if(mouse_event->buttons() & Qt::LeftButton)
    {
        this->move(mapToParent(mouse_event->pos() - offset));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can move the Ellipse using the `moveCenter` method.

```
void Label::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent* event){
    mousePressed = true; 
    if( mouse_event->buttons() & Qt::RightButton ){
        mCirc.setTopLeft(event->pos());
        mCirc.setBottomRight(event->pos());
    }
    if( mouse_event->buttons() & Qt::LeftButton) {
        offset = event->pos();
        center = mCirc.center();
    }
}

void Label::mouseMoveEvent ( QMouseEvent * mouse_event )
{
    ...
    if(mouse_event->buttons() & Qt::LeftButton) {
        QPoint delta = mouse_event->pos() - offset;    
        mCirc->moveCenter( center + delta);
    }
    update();
}
```

You might also want to guard the other action with a check for the right button.

```
void Label::mouseMoveEvent ( QMouseEvent * mouse_event )
{
    if(mouse_event->type() == QEvent::MouseMove &&  mousePressed == true){
        if(mouse_event->buttons() & Qt::RightButton) {
            mCirc.setBottomRight(mouse_event->pos());
        }
        if(mouse_event->buttons() & Qt::LeftButton) {
            QPoint delta = mouse_event->pos() - offset;    
            mCirc->moveCenter( center + delta);
        }
        update();
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer if i do    [if (mouse_event-> buttons () & Qt :: LeftButton) {
                   mCirc.setBottomRight (mouse_event-> pos ());
}  if (mouse_event-> buttons () & Qt :: RightButton) {   mCirc.moveCenter (mouse_event-> pos () - offset);  }] I can draw with the left button but if I want to move with the right button the ellipse disappears.

Comment: but when I do [ mCirc.setBottomRight (mouse_event-> pos ()); if (mouse_event-> buttons () & Qt :: RightButton){  mCirc.moveCenter (mouse_event-> pos () - offset);
}]I can draw ellipse  but when I click on the left button, ellipse resizes it  alone by moving it I want it to stay the same and moving it.

Comment: you are right. for this to work correctly we need to remember the original center and add the delta to that.

Comment: there is a problem of + operator not found that accepts a left-handed operand of type qTextStream no conversion acceptable.

Comment: Thank you  very much for your help it's finally working.

Comment: the same thing for the rectangle but for the line I do translate (offset) it does not work
I have to remenber the original  center or dx and dy ?

Comment: maybe ask that as a new question? that way you can show me the relevant code.